# How to construct a template that can call and return two different types

Tags: c++, templates

I'm working on some code where I have two classes each with a method that returns said class with a specific value. Now these two class have different names and the methods which returns said class with a specific value have different names, however the value is the same.

example

```
   class_a a = class_a::get_value_a()
   class_b b = class_b::get_value_b()

   a.value() == b.value() is true
```

Now what I'm trying to make is a generic way to get this value using template

example

```
   class_generic g_a = class_generic::get_value<class_a>();
   class_generic g_b = class_generic::get_value<class_b>();

   g_a.value() == g_b.value() is true
```

But when making the template I tried to do the following

```
template <typename T> T class_generic::get_value()
{
  if (typeid(T).hash_code() == typeid(class_a).hash_code())
  {
    return class_a::get_value_a()
  }
  if (typeid(T).hash_code() == typeid(class_b).hash_code())
  {
    return class_b::get_value_b();
  }
}
```

But this will not compile and it seems to me that it tries to resolve both return types and converts one.

So how do I do this correctly?

regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply [template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization). e.g.

```
// primary template
template <typename T> 
T class_generic::get_value();

// explicit specialization for T = class_a
template <> 
class_a class_generic::get_value<class_a>()
{
  return class_a::get_value_a();
}

// explicit specialization for T = class_b
template <> 
class_b class_generic::get_value<class_b>()
{
  return class_b::get_value_b();
}
```

Or apply [Constexpr If](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) (since C++17), whose condition is evaluated at compile-time, and then could avoid the issue your code snippet encountered. e.g.

```
template <typename T>
T class_generic::get_value()
{
  if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, class_a>)
  {
    return class_a::get_value_a();
  } 
  else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, class_b>)
  {
    return class_b::get_value_b();
  } 
  else 
  {
    // return something else..
  }
}
```

Comment: In the question, both of the theoretical functions return `class_generic`. If it is important that the function returns the same object type (say to store in a list) this won't work. I think the intended use requires some clarification.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox `T` is specified as the return type, so I suppsoe `class_a` or `class_b` is the return type. And both could be converted to `class_generic`?

Comment: I have posted a very simplified version of the code I'm working with just to illustrate the problem I needed to solve. But songyuanyao is right I need the different classes as return type.

Comment: @songyuanyao I was working in this direction, seem I had made a mistake, thank you for your simple example. I do not work on C++17 so i cannot use that example.

Answer (score 0):

In current Standard, this can be done as

```
struct class_generic {
    template<typename T> T get_value() {
        if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, class_a>) {
            return class_a::get_value_a();
        }
        else return class_b::get_value_b();
    }
};
```

Note that if the two alternatives cannot be compiled simultaneously, i.e. one part of code only compiles for one template parameter value, and other for the other, they should be different branches of the same `if constexpr/else` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Aside the proper solutions already given, you should notice that typeid() is a runtime operator to inspect polymorphic type at runtime, whether templates are a compile time issue. Thus typeid would not be evaluated during template evaluation in your code.